# How can I prevent TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when submitting empty form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, conditional-statements

Ok so my code works great but when I hit submit while the input field is empty my .map method doesnt have a input value to add to the end of the API string to search for so I get a typeError: cannot read property of map undefined.    because input is my state and if I dont enter a string into the input field the state doesnt get updated so the .map method has no updated state to go off of.
SO how would I set the input field to require text to be entered before the submit button will even call the function "SearchApi"?
I was trying to set conditionals but it didnt seem to work....like....if input.length < 1 { setInput("E.T")  just so it has something to search for and doesn't return an error. I also was looking online at react form validation tutorials but I feel like maybe i'm going about this all wrong.   Any help would be appriciated thank you!

````
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const SearchBar = () => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);
const [upcoming, setUpcoming] = useState([]);


 

// Input Field
const onUserInput = ({target}) => {
    setInput(target.value);

}

//  Api Call 
const SearchApi = (event) => {
    const aUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=fde5ddeba3b7dec3fc1f51852ca0fb95";
   const newUrl = aUrl +'&query=' + input;
 event.preventDefault();
       
    fetch(newUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
       setSearch(data.results);
        
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error!! Data interupted!:', error)
    })
    }

    
      return (
        //   Heading
<div>
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Movie Search Extravaganza!</h1>

        {/* Input Field and Button Form */}
      <form>
        <input value={input} onChange={onUserInput} type="text" className="searchbar" aria-label="searchbar" placeholder="search" name="movie" required/>
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit" onClick={SearchApi} aria-label="searchbutton" className="searchBtn">Movie Express Search</button>
      </form>
     </div>

    <div className="byName-container">
        <h1 className="row-label" tabIndex="0">Movies Related To Your Search</h1>
      <ul className="flexed-search">
          {search.map((item) => 
          <div className="poster-container">
          <li className="list-item"  key={item.id}>
           <img className="image-element" tabIndex="0" alt="movie poster" aria-label={item.title} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${item.poster_path}`} />
          <h3 className="posterTitle">{item.title}</h3>
          </li>
          </div>
       )}
      </ul>
        </div>
 

<div className="trending-container">
    <h1 className="row-label" tabIndex="0">This Weeks Trending Tittles</h1>
    <ul className="flexed-trending">
    {trending.map((it) => 
    <div className="poster-container">
    <li className="list-item"  key={it.id}> <img className="image-element" tabIndex="0" aria-label={it.title} alt="movie poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${it.poster_path}`} />
    <h3 className="posterTitle">{it.title}</h3>
    </li>
    </div>
    )}
    </ul>
</div>


<div className="upcoming-container"> 
<h1 className="row-label" tabIndex="0">Upcomming Movies</h1>
 <ul className="flexed-upcoming">
 {upcoming.map((inn) => 
 <div className="poster-container">
 <li className="list-item"  key={inn.id}>
 <img className="image-element" tabIndex="0" alt="movie poster" aria-label={inn.title} title={`${inn.title}: ==>  ${inn.overview}`} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${inn.poster_path}`} />
 <h3 className="posterTitle">{inn.title}</h3>
 </li>
 </div>
 )}
 </ul>


</div>
        

        </div>


    )
};

export default SearchBar;```
````

Comment: There are many ways to validate a form, it kinda depends on the style your going with. But if I understand you correctly your tried the update the input value in SearchApi function if its empty ```if input.length < 1 { setInput("E.T") }```? Whenever you update a state, it is doing so async, meaning that if you'r trying to send the updated input to the url - then it is still going to use the old value before the setState call.

Comment: So basically, if setInput is initialized with an empty string.  and then I try to set a conditional in the OnUserInput function above, would I be able to use "if input.length < 1 { setInput("E.T") }"  else setInput(target.value) ?   like just saying if theres no text enterred in the input field then update the state to "E.T"?   or else update the state to target.value?   IM just using this way as a means of keep it from giving the user errors when they hit submit.  if you can explain another way to do it id be very intersted to hear it, im so lost right now on how to go about this.

Comment: "required" is enough, no conditional function needed, just see my answer

Comment: You could, but if your changing the input value to E.T whenever its empty, it would also change the input field to E.T, which could confuse the user. The best and easiest approach is probably to do something like MB_ suugest. But if you for some reason would like to check it inside the SearchApi you could always use a private variable: 
```let queryInput = input.length >= 1 ? input : "E.T";``` and  ```const newUrl = aUrl + "&query=" + queryInput;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small mistake in your form

Change this :

```
<form>
...
<button type="submit" onClick={SearchApi} aria-label="searchbutton" className="searchBtn">
   Movie Express Search
  </button>
</form>
```

By :

```
<form onSubmit={SearchApi}>
...
<button type="submit" aria-label="searchbutton" className="searchBtn">
   Movie Express Search
  </button>
</form>
```

The "required" of the input will work. **Demo:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-skcc3v?file=src%2FApp.js)

---

**PS :** Check the keys in all your map functions

```
  {search.map(item => (
    <div className="poster-container">     //pass the key here and do the same for others
      <li className="list-item" key={item.id}>
```

Comment: thank you MB_  that worked perfectly, as well with the keys, So if I add keys to the container div's instead of the li items it will cover everything?

Comment: Yep ! You always put the key in the first element of your map and that will cover everything

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make required explicit with

```
required={true}
```

Comment: required={true} and required it's the same thing (it's true by default)